# Separate the memory router and browser router in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have created a react application with a home page and survey containing 15 questions on 15 pages.
I used a `BrowserRouter` to wrap the home page in the `'/'` route. I listed the 15 pages under the `MemoryRouter` to make it display under the `'/apply'` route. The issue here is the initial entry is visible in the `'/'` route. `MemoryRouter` should not be visible in the `'/'` route. It should be there on the '/apply' path alone.

```
import React from "react";
import BusinessType from "./BusinessType";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  MemoryRouter,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import Howmuch from "./Howmuch";
import Seeking from "./Seeking";
import Date from "./Date";
import AnnualRevenue from "./Annualrevenue";
import Creditscore from "./Creditscore";
import BusinessName from "./BusinessName";
import Industry from "./Industry";
import Deposit from "./Deposit";
import Zipcode from "./Zipcode";
import Name from "./Name";
import Phone from "./Phone";
import Email from "./Email";
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import Require from "./Require";
import Apply from "./Apply";

function App() {
  return(
    <div>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />}  />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
       
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/apply']} initialIndex={0}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/apply' element={<BusinessType />} />
          <Route path='/Qn2' element={<Howmuch />} />
          <Route path='/Qn3' element={<Seeking />} />
          <Route path='/Qn4' element={<Date />} />
          <Route path='/Qn5' element={<AnnualRevenue />} />
          <Route path='/Qn6' element={<Creditscore />} />
          <Route path='/Qn7' element={<BusinessName />} />
          <Route path='/Qn8' element={<Industry />} />
          <Route path='/Qn9' element={<Deposit />} />
          <Route path='/Qn10' element={<Zipcode />} />
          <Route path='/Qn11' element={<Name />} />
          <Route path='/Qn12' element={<Phone />} />
          <Route path='/Qn13' element={<Email />} />
          <Route path='/final' element={<Require />} />
          <Route path='/congrats' element={<Apply />} />
        </Routes>
      </MemoryRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is there a compelling reason as to why you are using two separate routers? What is the use case? What is the issue you are observing versus what is expected? What are the steps to reproduce?

Comment: I used two separate routers because all pages of the survey should be under the '/apply' route. browser router for rendering the homepage, about us page with separate route names

Comment: Is there an issue with rendering them all in an `"/apply/*"` route all under the same `BrowserRouter`?

Comment: Are you saying the issue is that the `BusinessType` component is being rendered when the URL path is `"/"`?

Comment: yes, it is rendered under '/'

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your post and comments correctly it seems you are saying that the `BusinessType` component is being rendered even though the current URL path is `"/"`. The issue here is that the `MemoryRouter` path matching isn't coupled to the browser's address bar and you've initialized to `"/apply"` and so that is the "path" that is matched and rendered regardless what the URL is in the browser's address bar.

> I used two separate routers because all pages of the survey should be
> under the '/apply' route.

In this case I'd suggest rendering all these routes in the main `BrowserRouter` under the appropriate route paths.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import BusinessType from "./BusinessType";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
...

function App() {
  return(
    <div>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home />}  />
            <Route path="/apply">
              <Route index element={<BusinessType />} />     // "/apply"
              <Route path='/Qn2' element={<Howmuch />} />    // "/apply/qn2" 
              <Route path='/Qn3' element={<Seeking />} />    // "/apply/qn3"
              <Route path='/Qn4' element={<Date />} />       // "/apply/qn4"
              ...
              <Route path='/Qn12' element={<Phone />} />     // "/apply/qn12
              <Route path='/Qn13' element={<Email />} />     // "/apply/qn13
              <Route path='/final' element={<Require />} />  // "/apply/final"
              <Route path='/congrats' element={<Apply />} /> // "/apply/congrats"
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```